# is there anyway to embed an OLE object in Word under macos and use an external program to process the OLE object when double clicking?

Tags: macos, ms-word, office-addins, ole, com-automation

guys!

we are developing a formula editor.
we want to insert our formula in Word (the formula image is normally displayed in Word) and edit again, just like xlsx files.
when double clicking, we want to launch our editor program to edit the formula and then replace it in Word.

we have already done that on Windows, but under the macOS, we are confused because we do not know how to implement them.

can you please tell me if that possible? is there a similar function implementation of office word under macos?
any advice or suggestion is welcome!

Comment: No, because OLE is a Windows-only technology that does not work on other platforms. There is no alternative capability for MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible because OLE is based on the COM technology which exists on Windows only.

As a possible solution you may consider creating an Office web add-in which can be installed on all platforms from web browsers to Mac OS. See [Develop Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview) for more information.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.